# In mvktoolnix, what is command to extract a part of video, audio files?

Tags: video-editor, mkv

In mvktoolnix, what is command to extract a part of video, audio files (mp4, mkv, mp3,...)? say like

`extract filename from 00:5:30 to 1:10:25`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be easily accomplished using my old friend mkvmerge and the incredibly versatile `--split` option. For your specified case the following should do the job:

```
mkvmerge -o output.mkv --split parts:00:05:30-01:10:25 input.mkv
```

The time elements are specified as HH:MM:SS.nnnnnnnnn:

1. **HH** represents number of hours
2. **MM** represents number of minutes
3. **SS** represents number of seconds
4. **nn** represents number of nanoseconds

And as you can see from the example I have given the start and finish times are simply separated by the `-` sign.

Further information on this aspect of the `--split` option can be seen on the [mkvmerge man pages](https://manpages.org/mkvmerge).